# How can I add fields to a json file from the fields in the front end in a react application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a config.json file where I have the values for the dropdown on the home page of my application. The values are been populated dynamically, now what i am trying to do is enable the user to add values to the config file from the text fields present in the front end. I am posting a request and have been able to push the values to the config file as well but I am unable to handle the condition where the dropdown values are already present. I have three fields Controller, test and Protocol and I want to apply the logic which is commented in the server side code which I have shown below. Can anyone please help to achieve this logic. Any help is much appreciated.

Regards

Part where help is needed to build the logic.

```js
// We found controller so need to check for test
// if test found nothing to do
// if not found add test
// if test found need to check for protcol
```

Comment: Whats the error?

Answer (score 0):

In your `config.json`, `Test` is an array of elements. Hence `d.Test === req.body.test` will not yield the intended result. I assume you're trying to check whether `req.body.test` is present in the `Test` array, and not if they match.

```js
const { controller, test, protocol } = req.body;
const index = config.controllers.findIndex((c) => c.Name === controller);
if (index === -1) {
    config.controllers.push({
        Name: controller,
        Test: [test],
        Protocol: [protocol],
    });
} else {
    // Check if test exists in Test array...
    if (!config.controllers[index].Test.includes(test)) {
        config.controllers[index].Test.push(test);
    } else {
        // Check if protocol exists in Protocol array...
        if (!config.controllers[index].Protocol.includes(protocol)) {
            config.controllers[index].Protocol.push(protocol);
        }
    }
}

// Rest of your code.
```

BTW, it is a good idea to destructure res.body and the values in variables, will help you write cleaner looking code. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response @Rohan. So there are three things Controller, Test and Protocol. If controller is there then i look for test if controller is not there i add the controller. Similar goes for the test and the protocol as well. I tried the solution but its not working

Comment: Hey @Jayashri , what part of is not working? P.S., if you intend to push the protocol if the 'Test' is not already present, you have to add a line after `...Test.push(test)`: `config.controllers[index].Protocol.push(protocol);`. (I tested the code once, seems to work. Can you elaborate on the issue you're facing?)

Comment: I have edited my code. Now I am getting the issue of 'Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client'. Can you please help me fix this

Comment: I'm guessing this error was thrown because you're trying to send two responses. Note that it should never happen in your code that you're sending 2 responses for 1 request. One way to prevent that would be to add a `return;` after `res.json`s. Also note that once you return, the code after it won't run, so structure your code in such a way that everything you need to do is completed before a response is sent, and then you can return.